# how to get when Project updated time from task table or billingTimes?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I got this problem I am trying to get the last task updated task related to project  and how did this update by getting the last billingTime
also I have Copley of design Questions

- What is the best way to get project and last updated time form task? should I use the *createdOn* column Form *billingTime*.
- should I add new column on project table to record the last updated task?

[image]

***my Query:***

```
SELECT     p.projectID, p.projectName, t.lastUpdate, billingsTimes.userID
FROM         Tasks AS t INNER JOIN
                      Projects_tasks ON t.taskID = Projects_tasks.taskID INNER JOIN
                      Projects AS p ON Projects_tasks.projectID = p.projectID INNER JOIN
                      billingsTimes ON t.taskID = billingsTimes.taskID
GROUP BY p.projectName, p.projectID, t.lastUpdate, billingsTimes.userID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to add a new column to your project table.  Looks like you already have a relationship setup between the 2 tables.  If you're looking at getting the last updated time  for a given project, try this:

```
SELECT     p.projectID, p.projectName, MAX(t.lastUpdate) as 'Last Updated Time'
FROM         Tasks AS t INNER JOIN
                      Projects_tasks ON t.taskID = Projects_tasks.taskID INNER JOIN
                      Projects AS p ON Projects_tasks.projectID = p.projectID
GROUP BY p.projectName, p.projectID
```

--EDIT

To show the `UserId` as well, try this:

```
SELECT     p.projectID, p.projectName, BillingsTimes.UserId, MAX(t.lastUpdate) as 'Last Updated Time'
FROM         Tasks AS t INNER JOIN
                      Projects_tasks ON t.taskID = Projects_tasks.taskID INNER JOIN
                      Projects AS p ON Projects_tasks.projectID = p.projectID INNER JOIN
                      BillingsTimes ON t.taskID = BillingsTimes.taskID
GROUP BY p.projectName, p.projectID, BillingsTimes.UserId
```

Comment: one small Question I got it know but also I need to get userID Form billingTime Table

Comment: You should be able to just add it to your select statement, add a join to the table, and add it to your group by statement and be good to go.  I'll edit my post above.

Comment: is their are away to remove the  duplicate entry in userID column because I try distinct and it is not working I'm trying to make it like excel sheet